# Drop Down List not getting populated

Tags: c#, webforms, sqldataadapter

I have a c# code line as,

```
using (SqlDataSource sqlds = new SqlDataSource(ConnectionString(), SelectCommand()))
            {
                drop1.DataSource = sqlds;
                drop1.DataTextField = "UserName";
                drop1.DataBind();
            }
```

now it's not populating my dropdownlist,

```
<asp:DropDownList id="drop1" runat="server" />
```

so I want to check if sql is returning data or not

if i put line break, I am not sure how to find out if sql is returning data, I am using using select statement and connection string for gridview and it works but not with drop down list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure you have your sqlquery into select command then you need convert you 
sqldatasource select command into dataview.

```cs
 string query = "select yourfield from yourtable";

using (SqlDataSource sqlds = new SqlDataSource(conn.ConnectionString, query))
{
   System.Data.DataView dv = (System.Data.DataView)sqlds.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
        if (dv.Count > 0)
        {
            DropDownList1.DataSource = sqlds;
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "yourfield";
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
        }
  }
```

Comment: +1, thanks sir, dv.count is telling me 5 and there are 5 records in table too

Comment: however it didn't populated drop down list

Comment: am not sure what you mean by that sir

Comment: Sorry, type mistake  be sure your sql query is correct. and if your selectcommand has exact value.

Comment: how would dv.count has 5 records, if sql query isn't correct sir ?

Comment: please read this question and my comment on it, and then update your answer and I will accept it,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436882/drop-down-list-not-getting-populated-on-partial-post-back

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to put a breakpoint on `drop1.DataSource = sqlds;` and then move your mouse over `sqlds` and it should show you how many rows are contained in the DataSource.

Comment: thanks sir, but I couldn't find any rows property for datasource

Comment: There's no `rows` property, but Visual Studio should helpfully show you a `Count = x`. If this doesn't happen then there may be a problem with your query. If you have SQL Server Profiler, then that is what I would use next to get the exact query that's being sent to SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

your way of binding datasource to the dropdown is correct and same thing is working for me.

Possible errors can be

- in the `connectionString`. Verify if it is correct.
- in the Select Query. Verify if the `SelectCommand()` methods returns correct sql query.

use `Selected` event of the SqlDataSource to verify whether it returned any row i.e

```
   sqlds.Selected += new SqlDataSourceStatusEventHandler(sdl_Selected);
```

where sql_Selected is:

```
  void sdl_Selected(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
  {
      var a = e.AffectedRows;
  }
```

as a Side note - make sure your select query doesn't contain any string concatenation prone to sql injection. i.e. `SELECT UserName from [TableName] where certainCol ="+ variable`.

Don't do it

provide a sql parameter instead, and add the `SelectParameters` to your `SqlDataSource`

Comment: there's nothing wrong with select statement neither with connection string sir

Comment: then your query simply didn't return any row

Comment: then verify if you set correct DataTextField or verify if you don't empty your dropdown somewhere else. there is no reason for it to not run