# Drop Down List not getting populated on partial post back

Tags: c#, webforms, controls, postback

I am trying to populate a drop down list on partial post back, not sure why it's not working.

this works,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                 populatemyDropDownList();
            }
```

this doesn't work,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (IsPostBack)
                {
                     populatemyDropDownList();
                }
```

**Scenario**

***I click on button_1 in UpdatePanel_1, which then triggers a partial post back (no page refresh) and tries to populate DropDownList which is in UpdatePanel_2***

when I debug, I can see code behind method is triggering and going through this code but no gain, I think partial post back resets DropDownList ????

```
using (SqlDataSource sqlds = new SqlDataSource(ConnectionString(), SelectCommand()))
            {
                drop1.DataSource = sqlds;
                drop1.DataTextField = "UserName";
                drop1.DataBind();
            }
```

Comment: Then use the code after `"this works"`. The question is not yet clear.

Comment: Nope, thanks, I can't

Comment: Shouldn't it be populated from `button_1`'s click handler?

Comment: Thats what I am trying to do, but it's not working sir

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the dropdown and updatepanel markups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).IsInAsyncPostBack
```

to check if you're in an asynchronous postback.

However, i would not rely your logic on postbacks(or `!IsPostBack`) and `IsInAsyncPostBack`. Instead i would use the correct events. In this case you want to handle `button_1`'s click event to fill the `DropDownList` in `UpdatePanel2`.

Note that you should make `UpdatePanel2`'s UpdateMode `Conditional`. Then you can call `UpdatePanel2.Update()` manually after you've filled the `DropDownList`.

Comment: thanks, I was doing everything except, calling updatepanel2.update() , :)